# Text to Speech API not calling setOnUtteranceCompletedListener

Tags: android, text-to-speech

**What I want:**
I want to be notified when TextToSpeech program has done speaking and I want to perform some GUI task when it finishes the speaking task.
**What I know:**
**setOnUtteranceCompletedListener** can be used as a call back which should notify me that it has findished speaking.It's depriciated in API level 15 but still it should work.
**setOnUtteranceProgressListener** is an other and a better way to receive call backs for starting finsishing and error notifications. Minimum API level 15 is required to implement this interface. I changed my minimum sdk version to 15 and tried this method as well but it didn't work for me as well.
Here is my **code**

```
    public class SpeakingNotepad extends AppCompatActivity  implements TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener{

    Button btnSpeak;
    EditText etText;
    TextToSpeech speaker;
    SpeechRecognizer voiceRecognizer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speaking_notepad);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        speaker = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                speaker.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            }
        });
        speaker.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(etText.getText().length()>0)
                   speaker.speak(etText.getText().toString(),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }
        });
        etText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etText);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
        Log.d("textToSpeech","completed");
        Toast.makeText(this,"completed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        btnSpeak.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to set the listener inside onInit() function of Your TTS implementation. And If You want to do some UI changes, do it inside UI Thread.....

Comment: Also, you set tts params with `HashMap` object when you call speak(). Refer my answer for detail code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** : Use `Handler` instead of `runOnUiThread()` method.

---

I recommend you `OnUtteranceProgressListener` because this API has more method to listen that TextToSpeech's state is changing.

However, if you want to use OnUtteranceCompleted Listener, edit like as below:

```
 public class SpeakingNotepad extends AppCompatActivity  implements TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener{
    private final String UTTER_ID = "utterance";
    private final int TTS_DONE = 99;

    Button btnSpeak;
    EditText etText;
    TextToSpeech speaker;
    SpeechRecognizer voiceRecognizer;

    HashMap<String, String> ttsOptions;
    MainViewHandler g_hnd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        g_hnd = new MainViewHandler(SpeakingNotepad.this);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        speaker = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                ttsOptions = new HashMap<String, String>();
                ttsOptions.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, UTTER_ID);

                speaker.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            }
        });
        speaker.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(etText.getText().length()>0)
//                    speaker.speak(etText.getText().toString(),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
                    speaker.speak(etText.getText().toString(),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,ttsOptions);
            }
        });
        etText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
        if (utteranceId.equals(UTTER_ID)) {
            Log.d("textToSpeech", "completed");
            /*
            // for more common usage, use `Handler` instead of `runOnUiThread()`.
            // block
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(SpeakingNotepad.this, "completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    btnSpeak.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            });
            */

            // then, you just call `sendMessage()`.
            g_hnd.sendMessage(TTS_DONE);
        }
    }

    private static class MainViewHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<SpeakingNotepad> mAct;

        MainViewHandler(SpeakingNotepad act) {
            mAct = new WeakReference<SpeakingNotepad>(act);
        }

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            SpeakingNotepad act = mAct.get();
            if (act != null) {
                act.handleMessage(msg)
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
            case TTS_DONE:
                Toast.makeText(SpeakingNotepad.this, "completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                btnSpeak.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you bro for your detailed answer. I tried your code but still not showing any toast and also not changing the background color of the button

Comment: Did you try to use `runOnUIThread`? See in method `onUtteranceCompleted()` one more time...

Comment: sorry bro I forgot to replace one line of code.. now i have changed it and it has done the magic for me :) thank you so much

Comment: @Hasan Abdullah What is the point that you want to make working? Please let me know more detail about your problem.

Comment: Sir, Thank you for your comment. At last I found my mistakes. 
First, I didn't pass HashMap and secondly missed `getActivity().runOnUIThread` (for fragment). I thought passing HashMap is optional.

Comment: over API 21, HashMap object is optional thing that you thought because `onUtteranceCompleted()` method is deprecated. But, if you want to use this method, you must pass HashMap.